# When a WaveDataFlow is scheduled - where the information is stored? Which metadata type is referred to view

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, einstein-analytics, einstein, dataflow

We have a job scheduled **WaveDataFlow** to run every 2hours in our Production org. And some user has modified the scheduled job to run every 24hrs instead of 2h.

We have verified the AuditTrailSetup but could not found any information who has changed the scheduled job on WaveDataFlow.

Also we have Ownbackup tool for both metadata and data backups, but we are not able to locate exact metadata type where the information is stored related to scheduled job changes.

Do you know where can we find the information in terms of Metadata type.